# Installing a Go package on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, go, arm, package, raspberry-pi

I am currently using Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi Model B+. I already have Go installed and want to install [scollector](http://bosun.org/scollector/).  I tried

```
$ go get bosun.org/cmd/scollector
```

but got the error

```
package net/http/cookiejar: unrecognized import path "net/http/cookiejar"
```

I also tried to install via the ARMv6 binary. I ran the chmod +x command on the binary and then tried to execute it using `./scollector-linux-armv6` but got an error saying "Text file busy."

Answer (score 3):

This message came up at https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/342: you likely have the old version of Go that came with your distribution and it lacks that package. You can download a recent go (1.4.2 as I'm writing) for ARMv6 from [Dave Cheney's site](http://dave.cheney.net/unofficial-arm-tarballs). You'll probably want to unpack that, move/rename the resulting dir to `~/go`, and change your `.bashrc` to set up a PATH and GOPATH in your homedir by adding lines like:

```
# optional; makes bin/, pkg/ and src/ under your homedir for Go
export GOPATH=~    
# puts the 'go' tool + built go binaries + anything else in ~/bin in PATH
# remove the :~/bin bit if you don't want it
export PATH=~/go/bin:~/bin/:$PATH
# lets Go know that it's not in /usr/local/go
export GOROOT=~/go
```

then `. ~/bashrc` or log out and in to put the latest in your environment. You might then run into other problems; if you get stuck, maybe post those as additional questions with all the details you can and a reference to this question. And `bash`-specific details vary if you use another shell.

You can also (as user allonhadaya points out) cross-compile: build binaries to be transferred to your Raspberry Pi from a desktop or laptop. Tools like [goxc](https://github.com/laher/goxc) help manage this (you can also do it by hand with environment variables like `GOOS` and `GOARCH` if you want). [In Go 1.5, scheduled to come out at the end of 2015, it will get simpler.](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/03/03/cross-compilation-just-got-a-whole-lot-better-in-go-1-5)

"Text file busy" right after `chmod` is apparently [something that happens](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9547). Running `sync` between the chmod and running the binary may help. It could plausibly happen if the file were still downloading, too. Either way, it's still useful to have a Go environment for any other projects you want to build or potentially any coding you want to do yourself.

Good luck with what you're doing!

Comment: Another approach to running the latest go on a raspberry pi is cross compiling. I've had success using [goxc](https://github.com/laher/goxc) to do the job.

Comment: Ha, good point. Been running Dave's Go builds on an ARM Chromebook for a while so reflexively suggested the Raspberry Pi version of that.

Comment: Added a para on cross-compilation referencing goxc (and Go 1.5, which promises to simplify cross-compilation with the built-in tools).